# Did a program or have taken part in a program?

Tags: american-english, formality

I want to say that I "did" a student exchange program in another country.
which way is the correct way of writing that in a formal letter / application:

1. I have taken part in a student exchange program in Japan
2. I did a student exchange program in Japan
3. I have been in a student exchange program in Japan

Comment: (1) has the right tone for me.

Comment: 4. *I went on a student exchange program in Japan.* 5. *I took part in a student exchange program in Japan.* 6. *I was part of a student exchange program in Japan.*

Answer (score 1):

*I was a participant in a student exchange program in Japan*

It sounds more formal.

Comment: I agree this sounds more formal, and add that this kind of formality is appropriate for a cover letter outlining your experience and achievements. To say "I did a student exchange program..." sounds less formal, and is less appropriate in such a letter. It would not be impolite, just more casual than the reader might expect.

Answer (score 0):

> I have taken part in a student exchange program in Japan.

has the right tone for me; or "took part".